# Kubelet CoreOs FlexVolume plugin

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, kubelet

I have a DigitalOcean flexVolume on CoreOS.  I am following this documentation for CoreOS from [TonyZou](https://github.com/tonyzou/flexvolumes).

> Note that CoreOS mounts /usr as read-only so instead you'll want to add --volume-plugin-dir=/etc/kubernetes/volumeplugins to KUBELET_ARGS in /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.env and put the plugins there instead.
>
> Restart kubelet with systemctl restart kubelet.service.

I create file in /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.env with content:

> KUBELET_ARGS=--volume-plugin-dir=/etc/kubernetes/volumeplugins

And my driver in /etc/kubernetes/volumeplugins folder.  However, the pod using the flexvolume driver keeps remaining in ContainerCreating status.  Not sure if the kubelet.env file is getting picked up by kubelet.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the describe tell you?

Comment: not much except either the mount failed or that the pod has been assigned to node ip.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe add the  /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.env file to your kubelet systemd unit. Something like

EnvironmentFile=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.env

This ensures that the kubelet service will pick up your env file.

Comment: I abandoned using flexvolume for now.  I am using rook.io now and it is awesome so far!

Answer (score 0):

Your kubelet didn't pick up the `kubelet.env`.

1. If you wanna run the kubelet manually, you should add `KUBELET_ARGS=--volume-plugin-dir=/etc/kubernetes/volumeplugins` in your shell environment.
2. If you wanna run the kubelet by systemd, you should add the `kubelet.env` in your kubelet systemd config file and reload the config file.